# Упрочнение или упрочение?

Tags: стилистика, выбор-слов, синонимы

Как правильно:

*Стал символом упро`чне`ния гражданского мира*

или

*Стал символом упро`че`ния гражданского мира*?

Мой вопрос об употреблении слова.

Answer (score 2):

В политической риторике времён КПСС закрепился только вариант "*упрОчение*" (мира, рядов или единства каких-нибудь прогрессивных сил, Советской власти и т. п. - от глагола упрОчить)"; если требуется менее высокопарный, нейтральный стиль (без ассоциации с ритуальными речами прежних эпох), то подойдёт синоним "**укрепление**". В технической литературе преобладает вариант "*упрочнЕние*" (сплавов, механических соединений), хотя в горном деле можно встретить "упрОчение" (горных пород).

Answer (score 0):

[Словарь сочетаемости слов](http://vassilenkoanatole.narod.ru/slovar-sochet_slov.pdf) и [Большой толковый словарь](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D1%83%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5&all=x) дают только **упрочение мира**.

Answer (score 0):

**Стал символом упрочения (упрочнения) гражданского мира.**

Первый вариант более употребителен для данной тематики, но второй тоже возможен.

**Из словаря:**

**УПРОЧЕНИЕ**,  к Упрочить и Упрочиться. Стремление к упрочению мира. У. власти. У. авторитета родителей. У. политического положения.

**УПРОЧИТЬ,**  что. Сделать прочным, надёжным; укрепить. У. мир. У. договор между государствами. У. финансовое положение предприятия.

**УПРОЧНИТЬ**, -св. 1. Сделать более прочным, крепким. У. бетон. У. конструкцию машины. У. каменную кладку. 2. **=Упрочить.** У. дружбу. У. свой авторитет. У. положение властей.

**Примеры**

**1) Упрочнение (26 примеров, обычно в технике)**

«При этом заодно происходит и азотирование ― **упрочнение,** существенно повышающее износостойкость», ― пояснил автор разработки, доктор технических наук Николай Коваль. [неизвестный. Информация // Юный техник, 2013]

**2) Упрочение (в остальных случаях)**

Надо строго различать между этой чуждой нам, разрушительной антибольшевистской «самокритикой» и нашей, большевистской самокритикой, имеющей своей целью насаждение партийности, **упрочение** Советской власти... [И. В. Сталин. «Правда», 1928]

Этика современности подсказывает нам только один ответ ― развитие, **упрочение** и расширение жизни и её высшего атрибута ― разума. [Александр Маркович. На пути к абсолютной морали (2003) // «Вестник США», 2003.07.23]

― **упрочение** общероссийской гражданской и духовно-нравственной общности. [Концепция: опыт, цели и задачи (2000) // «Жизнь национальностей», 2000.06.23]